# missing files at django-admin startproject

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I am learning Django & when following through I can create the startup project however it only brings one file.. so I cannot continue to start the Django development server. These are the instructions I followed so far:

[image]

How do I recreate those missing files as depicted in the instructions' tree . Please assist

Comment: see docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: after installing `django` run, `django-admin startproject mysite` , change name of project [mysite]

Answer (score -1):

I just realized that you need restart VS Code after installing Django i.e. after the instruction:

> (venv) $ python -m pip install Django

then re-run the '.\venv\Scripts\activate' to come back to the virtual environment before the running command ' *django-admin startproject personal_portfolio .* '
That solved it! First time install of Django requires an exit in VS code.